# iOS: Is it possible to detect if a track exists in music library?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I'm working on an app for a band and they'd like certain features to unlock if their album or singles are in the user's music library.

Is it possible to scan the library for a specific title?(and possibly check duration as well?)

Comment: You probably want to check if the songs are legit too

Comment: yea was thinking title with a matching duration. which can still be gotten around, but it'd require a lot of effort for the user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working search. This checks for a track that matches both the title and the artist name.

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *titlePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Sleep The Clock Around" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artistPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Belle & Sebastian" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo];

MPMediaQuery *trackSearch = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:[NSSet setWithObjects:titlePredicate,artistPredicate, nil]];

if(trackSearch.items.count > 0) NSLog(@"we found the track!");
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to do both, have a look at the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9), specifically the seconds on programmatically querying the media store and the item metadata (for the duration).